# My terminal is not opening ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-terminal

Lately, I downgraded my pip to 9.0.4 so as to install mpl_cursors, and then ran a code. Since then I tried restarting my laptop but to no avail. I see this upon clicking but nothing opens. Urgent help needed to submit an assignment. Also, I get a notification, a problem occurred when checking for new updates. Thank You.

[image]

Comment: There is not a lot of specific information ("then ran a code"). Few specific help can thus be offered. Apparently, you broke your software package management as well (notification you mention).